# How can I reference an element inside a control template

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

Say I wanna put a `CheckBox` inside a `Button`. Is there anyway for me to reference that checkbox in code? i.e. In Window1.cs I want to write something like: `testButton.innerCheckBox.DoStuff()`;

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                          
        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" ThemeColor="NormalColor">
        <Grid Width="32.083" Height="13.277">
            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RecognizesAccessKey="True" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="innerCheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CheckBox"/>
        </Grid>
        </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CheckBox innerCheckBox = testButton.Template.FindName("innerCheckBox", testButton) as CheckBox;
```

Comment: I love this site. Thanks for the speedy response.